# Save data is post using php front end

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, post-meta, media-library

I'm newbie,  i have a simple php file ,there is my data like, title, body content, feature image, category and 1 custom file
I want to save this data in my post
My coding look like this

```
$title="my title";
$content="demo body content";
$image="google.com/some-image-path.jpg";
$category="tesy cate";
$custom_post_filed="test custom filed";
```

I have code like this, i havr this content in my front-end.php
Please any brother help me how to this content automatically publish in my post, if conditions must apply please, thanks in advance

Comment: How does this relate to WordPress development? What have you tried? What *specific* problem are you having? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/383297/edit) to add more detail.

Comment: This is PHP separate from your WordPress site and you won't have the WordPress functions loaded? You could use [the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post) to create a new post. You'll need to set up authentication e.g. the new app passwords in WordPress 5.6.